# 13.04 on Macbook Air 2011 - Ran update and now boots into osx recovery

Tags: boot, 13.04, grub2, macbook

Recently I wiped OS X completely from my Macbook Air and installed Ubuntu 13.04 alone. This worked great because it even booted automatically into Ubuntu without needing to hold any keys.

Today, I ran the Ubuntu software update and apparently as the kernel and other things were updated, now it will boot directly into OS X recovery. Is there a way to fix this and boot into Ubuntu automatically again? I only have Ubuntu installed on this machine and I intend to keep it this way.

My Macbook Air is a 13' model 4,2 (late 2011)

Update: If I hold the Option key, I can choose the only HDD partition that is present and boot Ubuntu, but I'd like this to happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something went bad related to grub.

Boot to your Ubuntu installation and install and run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu). Without knowing more details about how your system is installed (UEFI vs. Legacy, separate /boot partition etc.), its hard to give further advise. But check the help found at that page as well.

Comment: My installation is the default one from 13.04 that wipes everything from the hard drive. I will try your suggestion and report back, thanks!